# Unable to delete records through jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Springboot i created a delete method in repository. I used this same repository method to delete the record in service method. Records not getting deleted. It throws exception.  Please advise.

Code:

```java
public interface SopCffDtlDependentRepository extends JpaRepository<SopCffDtlDependent,String>{

    String deleteByQuotationNo(String quotationNo);
    }


@Autowired
SopCffDtlDependentRepository sopCffDtlDependentRepository;


String noOfRecordsDeleted = sopCffDtlDependentRepository.deleteByQuotationNo(params.getQuotationNo());

                @Entity
                @Table(name = "SOP_CFF_DTL_DEPENDENT")
                public class SopCffDtlDependent {


                    @Column(name="NAME")
                    private String name;

                    @Column(name = "RELATIONSHIP")
                    private String relationShip;

                    @Column(name ="DOB")
                    private Date dob;

                    @Column(name="GENDER")
                    private String gender;

                    @Column(name="YEAR_OF_SUPPORT")
                    private Integer yearOfSupport;

                    @Id
                    @Column(name="QUOTATION_NO")    
                    private String quotationNo;

                    @Column(name="INVESTMENT_PREFER")   
                    private String investmentPrefer;

                    @Column(name="SEQUENCE_NO") 
                    private int sequenceNo;
}
```

Exception:

```
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call
```

Comment: Show us your entity classes.

Comment: I placed the entity class.

Answer (score 2):

You should add Modifying and Transactional annotation to delete by condition.I am not sure this is the reason by looking at your logs.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
void deleteByQuotationNo(String quotationNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use @Service it is preferred to put **@Transactional** annotation there:

```
public class SopCffDtlDependentServiceImpl implements SopCffDtlDependentService {
    @Autowired
    SopCffDtlDependentRepository repo;
    ...
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String deleteByQuotationNo(String quotationNo) {
        repo.deleteByQuotationNo(quotationNo);
```